# refresh post the values again, leads to again entry in database

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have my application where there are thousands of pages. I have found an issue when I post some values through the form and make their entries in database.

But when I refresh the page this leads to posting again and result in duplicate entries in database.

How can I overcome it?

When I post from the form, I check for the particular variable as

```
    if(isset($rq['submit'])){
       //my form code
    }
```

when i make entry in db from this block, and refreshing on same page then entry goes again in db!!

Comment: Redirect to the same page after the form is submitted, consider using `header('Location:<URLHERE>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the array variable so that when you check again whenever the page is refresh the value will be null or empty try the below code for just reference.

```
    if(isset($rq['submit'])){
        //my form code
        $rq['submit'] = '';
//      $rq['submit'] = null; you can try this too.
//      $rq['submit'] = array(); if it's an array.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following statements.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // do stuff
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
        exit;

    }
```

Comment: I can not use exit, is there any thing like i can set a hidden variable?

Answer (score 1):

Header the user to a new page :

```
if (isset($rq['submit'])) 
{
    //your form code

}
//best outside the if statement so user isn't stuck on a white blank page.
header("location: your_form_page.php");
exit;
```

By doing this the user who refreshes will be refreshing `your_form_page.php` which means it won't do the insert twice.

Comment: I can not use exit, is there any thing like i can set a hidden variable?

Comment: do you want to send any values to next page?

Answer (score 0):

i did that, by holding a key in a session variable and read it everytime when page is getting refresh, thanks all